# To what degree is "much" a negative polarity item?

Tags: negative-polarity-items

Consider a few sentences:

> 1. I read a lot.
> 2. ?I read much.
> 3. I don't read a lot.
> 4. I don't read much.
> 5. Do you read much?

This seems to suggest "much" is a negative polarity item, but then we can say things like "Much of it has to do with you not being here." So how much of a negative polarity item is "much"?

I am particularly interested in existing literature on this.

Comment: Yes, that suggests it, but that's all. I think Arnold Zwicky has written on the topic. It's just changing now and isn't in a particularly regular situation. There are hundreds of idioms in which the quantifiers figure without negation, and probly even more with negation. Certainly the ambiguity of _a lot_ has weakened the non-idiomatic uses of _much_ and _many_, but without a complete survey, one can't say much.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples using the quantifier version of *much* in non-negative contexts one can find on the internet are:

- *Now there was much grass in the place.* [John 6:10; Berean Standard Bible; Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com) (sounds archaic nowadays; often used thus in various Bible translations)
- *'There was much excitement over a message in a bottle' is a limited edition print of a watercolour painting by Julia Pamely* (sounds more reasonable)
- *There was much cheering and singing, and a bread fight had broken out across the dining hall.* [Quora](https://www.quora.com/There-was-much-cheering-and-singing-and-a-bread-fighting-across-the-dining-hall-Where-is-the-mistake-in-the-sentence) (sounds appropriate for literature evoking a bygone era)
- *Afterwards, there was much slapping of broad backs*. (again, evoking a bygone era)
- *There has been much discussion over this issue.* (sounds formal but not dated)
- *It seems, not long ago, there was much talk about the discovery of* ... (ditto; 'debate' collocates similarly)
- *There was much noise*. (sounds pretentious)
- ... *there was much money in the chest* (sounds outlandish).

I'd agree that 'much' doesn't mandate a negative context, but that one needs to be careful when one uses it in a positive context. Very careful.